# Erro Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Profile'

Tags: typescript, angular

Existe a seguinte variável declarada no script:

```
private profile: Profile;
```

Veja que é uma variável do tipo `Profile`.

Ao tentar atribuir um valor a variável, retorna o seguinte erro:

> Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Profile'.

O valor que está sendo atribuído é o seguinte:

```
this.profile = response.collection;
```

Entretanto verfiquei que a propriedade `response.collection` é uma instância da classe `Profile`:

```
console.log(response.collection instanceof Profile);
//true
```

**Por que a variável `profile` não aceita o valor de `response.collection` sendo que é uma instância da classe `Profile`?**

Comment: como o `response` está tipado?

Comment: e, por favor, utilize a tag correta. Typescript não é utilizado no angularjs

Comment: @mercador em relação a tag foi lapso da minha parte. Em relação a tipagem adicionei o ":any" e passou a funcionar, mas não entendo a necessidade de definir o tipo para o response.

Comment: pela mensagem de erro me parece que antes o response estava tipado como `Profile`

Comment: @mercador o `response` não, mas o `response.collection` sim, é uma instância da classe `Profile`.